# request.POST returns old values after updating it in custom middleware - django 1.11.9

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-middleware, django-rest-auth, django-request

I am using django 1.11.9

I want to add client_id and client_secret to the django POST request.

Here is how my middleware.py file looks like:

```
class LoginMiddleware(object):

def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

def __call__(self, request):
    # auth_header = get_authorization_header(request)
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.
    #Add Django authentication app client data to the request
    request.POST = request.POST.copy()
    request.POST['client_id'] = '12345678'
    request.POST['client_secret'] = '12345678'
    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response
```

Middleware is being successfully processed when I check it with a debugger. Thought when a view is called the 'client_id' and 'client_secret' fields are missing in the request.

**After some experimenting i figure out that request is not getting updated and when it is called in a different view, it returns old values.**

I am later using request in rest_framework_social_oauth2. And this is the point when 'client_id' and 'client_secret' disappear.

```
class ConvertTokenView(CsrfExemptMixin, OAuthLibMixin, APIView):
"""
Implements an endpoint to convert a provider token to an access token

The endpoint is used in the following flows:

* Authorization code
* Client credentials
"""
server_class = SocialTokenServer
validator_class = oauth2_settings.OAUTH2_VALIDATOR_CLASS
oauthlib_backend_class = KeepRequestCore
permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()
    # Use the rest framework `.data` to fake the post body of the django request.
    request._request.POST = request._request.POST.copy()
    for key, value in request.data.items():
        request._request.POST[key] = value

    url, headers, body, status = self.create_token_response(request._request)
    response = Response(data=json.loads(body), status=status)

    for k, v in headers.items():
        response[k] = v
    return response
```

I need to add client_id and client_secret to the request body, so it can be later used by rest_framework_social_oauth2.

What could be the problem? How to properly update the request?

Answer (score 0):

As you're working with `request` and processing a request, you have to implement `process_request` method, so the result will be something like:

```
class LoginMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.session['client_id'] = '12345678'
```

and then in your view:

```
def your_view(request):
    client_id = request.session['client_id']
```

Comment: I have tried adding it and doesn't seem to work. __init__ and __call__ functions should stay right? Otherwise i am getting an error: TypeError: object() takes no parameters. I also tried putting import pdb ; pdb.set_trace() in process_request function and I see that this function is not getting triggered.

Comment: I have also added some additional information in my question to give a bigger picture of the problem i am trying to solve. May be there are other workarounds?

Comment: You can try setting it (in `process_request`) into session in `request.session['client_id'] = '12345678'`  and then in your view get it from request.session. `__init__` and `__call__` are optional and are used if you need to preset some values or alter the way the object is created, which does not look like the case for you.

Comment: request.session works and is accessible in a different view. Though it is not a perfect solution for me. I am using rest_framework_social_oauth2 package and don't want to make changes to it's views. So ideally i need to update request.POST and pass the updated data accurately.

Comment: You can also try setting `request.POST = q_data` like here https://gist.github.com/LucasRoesler/700d281d528ecb7895c0   where `q_data` is the dictionary of values. This way or another orchestrating request happens in the same method.

Comment: All the methods above help to add information to the request object. Though when i get to another view all this information gets lost. E.g. in my middleware.py `request.POST = {'grant_type': ['convert_token'], 'backend': ['facebook'], 'token': ['1234'], 'client_id' = ['123'], 'client_secret' = ['123']}`. When request is called afterwards in the view of a 3d party package `client_id` and `client_secret` are missing. Seems that old request.POST dictionary is being used. Not sure how it is possible, but will need to find another workaround